# How can I return a downloadable file Django

Tags: django, templates

I am currently working on a project where I generate both a csv file and a config file. I would like to know if there is a way to have a href in my template that would trigger a download of those files to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` tag has one not so well-known attribute called: [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes):

```
<a href="{% url 'my_file_link' %}" download>download the file</a>
                                   ^ here
```

other way is to send header `Content-disposition: "attachment"` from server. If you are serving static files via Django (you probably shouldnt), do it in your view where you're composing the response. If you are serving the files from your webserver directly, here's an example for Nginx:

```
location /media {
    access_log off;
    root /var/www/project/media;

    location /media/downloads/ {
        # add the "force download" header for files in this directory
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment";
    }
}
```